# Switch branches without losing uncommitted work

Tags: git, branch, git-flow

Is there any way to switch from one `feature` branch to another, when the changes in the current `feature` branch are not yet ready to be committed?

I often find myself in a situation where I'm out of ideas when implementing a new feature or fixing a bug and I need to switch gears and work on something else. However, I do not know how to switch branches without losing all the uncommitted work I did up until that point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically have two options:

- Stashing: You can use `git stash` to save all the changes and keep them somewhere save. Afterwards, you will end up with a clean working directory so you can switch branches. Then, when you come back, you can use `git stash apply` to apply the changes from the last stash, so you’re back at where you left off.
- Commit: There is actually no reason why you couldn’t commit the changes. If you later want to change the commit, you can either use `git commit --amend` to amend that commit and “make it better”, or you can use `git reset --soft HEAD~1` to remove that commit (without losing the changes you did).

Comment: Stash is awesome, I do it all the time.